# Login & home page issues?

Tags: php, sql, authentication

Well i just got my login page to work as it should and of course this has caused something else to go wrong, the issue i am having is that when you go to the home page it should allow you to browse the home page and navigate to other regular pages not logged in to any sort of account (don't have to be registered or logged in to view these pages) but for some reason when i click on my EOI_home.php (which is my home page) as a non-logged in user it automatically takes me to my login.php (my login page) and forces me to log in before i can view the home page, meaning that i am not able too view the home page as a non-registered or non-logged in user which i should be able to do. Here is my code for my home page (EOI_home.php) :

```
<head>
<title>Expression of Interest</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Assign.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
require_once("nocache.php");
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION["who"]){
header("location: logoff.php");}
else {
$staff = $_SESSION["who"];
$access = $_SESSION["school_type"];
?>

<div class="title_background"><h2>Moving into Year 7 in a NSW government school in 2015</h2>
<h2>Information guide and Expression of Interest form for parents and carers</h2></div>
<p><img src="img1.jpg" width="750" height="550"></p>

<div class="right">
<?php
if ($access == S){
echo '<p><a href="process.php">Process EOI</a></p>';
echo '<p><a href="offerstatus.php">Print Offer Status Letters</a></p>';
}
if ($access == P){
echo '<p><a href="leavers.php">School Leavers</a></p>';
echo '<p><a href="comments_form.php">Add School Comments</a></p>';
}
echo '<p><a href="logoff.php">Logoff</a></p>';
}
?>
<p><a href="EOI_home.php">Home</a></p>
<p><a href="guidelines.htm">Guidelines</a></p>
<p><a href="options.htm">Your Secondary School Options</a></p>
<p><a href="eoi_form.php">Expression of Interest Form</a></p>
<p><a href="conpriv.htm">Privacy Statement and Contact Us</a></p>
<p><a href="login.php">Login</a></p>
</div>

<h1>Moving to secondary school</h1>
```

and here is my code for the login page (login.php) :

```
<body>

<?php
require_once("nocache.php");
$id = $_POST["id"];
$pword = $_POST["pword"];
$msgp = "";

if(!empty($_POST)) {
if(!empty($id) && !empty($pword)) {
    require_once("dbconn.php");
    $sql = "select username, school_type from school_info where username = '$id' and password = '$pword'";

    $rs = mysql_query($sql, $dbConn);

    if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["who"] = $id;
        $_SESSION["school_type"] = mysql_result($rs, 0, "school_type");

        header("location: EOI_home.php");
    }
 } else {
    header("location: login.php");
    $msgp = '<span class="error>Incorrect username and/or password</span>';     
}
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="login">

ID: <input type="text" name="id" /><?php echo $msgp; ?></td><br/>
pword: <input type="password" name="pword" /><br/>

<p><a href="EOI_home.php">Home</a></p>

<input type="submit" value="log in" />&nbsp;
<input type="reset" />

</form>
```

Here is the nochache.php code :

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Expires: -1");
?>
```

Here is also the code for logoff.php, just incase :

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("nocache.php");
session_destroy();
header("location: login.php");
?>
```

By the way the accounts have different access levels and with the different access levels different links are available on the home page e.g. access levels S and P.
If anyone could help me with a solution that would be really great, i am new to this stuff.

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should note that `session_start()` HAS to be run before any output to the browser.  Meaning it should be the VERY first thing at the top of the file after `<?php`, even before you opening `html` tags.

Comment: Is there any more PHP code in the `EOI_home.php` page? If the redirection is happening on that page, that would be the place to look for it.

Comment: Considering the issue in my first comment is not showing an error, I'm willing to bet the code that is causing he redirection is in `nocache.php`.  Please show us that code.

Comment: @Alpha nope that is all the PHP in the home page

Comment: @francis Thanks, then it's quite probably that the issue is on the nocache.php file as Sajan mentioned. Would you mind to share that as well?

Comment: @SajanParikh i have added the nochache.php code to my original post.

Comment: @Alpha I have included the nocache.php coding as well as the logoff.php coding just incase it is needed

Comment: Please do not remove your content in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    require_once("nocache.php");
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION["who"]){
        $staff = $_SESSION["who"];
        $access = $_SESSION["school_type"];
?>
```

Just comment header("location: logoff.php");

also check code for logoff is working or not

Comment: I have added my nocache.php and logoff.php code incase you wanted to check it as well.

Comment: ohk just comment `header("location: logoff.php");` line it will work. let me know